# Android TextView actionbar works inconsistently

Tags: java, android, textview, contextual-action-bar

I have an app about studying sacred Indian texts usually consisting of a verse and a commentary to this verse.
To open it up I use DisplayText activity which has an ActionBar popping up when user selects some text from either a verse or its commentary.

My problem is that it works inconsistently - on my Samsung Galaxy Note 2 it works OK, but on sony xperia Z2 once I try to touch the action button it exits the action bar and nothing happens.

**Samsung's Android version is 4.4.2 and Sony's version 4.4.4**

Please check out this very short [video for Sony device](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WAhVtvoaXU) and also [how it works for samsung device](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXpFeGqAcWY)
Please note that there are no error messages being shown in the LogCat view.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how I could possibly fix this problem
Also any ways to get a work around would be much appreciated as well.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Log.v("DEBUG", "DisplaTEXT onCreate - Starting Activity");
        try
        {
             m_context=this;
         mtxtTransl2View.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new CustomTextSelectCallback(mtxtTransl2View, false));
                     mtxtComment.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new CustomTextSelectCallback(mtxtComment, true));

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
class CustomTextSelectCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {
    public CustomTextSelectCallback(TextView tv, boolean b) {
        mTextView=tv;
        mbPurport=b;
    }

    //flag that selection is made in the purport, otherwise it is in shloka or translit

    private TextView mTextView;
    private boolean mbPurport;


    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "onCreateActionMode");
        //if(mbPurport)
        { 
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.text_selection_menu, menu);

            MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.cab_menu_fb);
            ShareActionProvider actionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)item.getActionProvider();

            actionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());             

            actionProvider.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(new OnShareTargetSelectedListener(){
                public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider source, Intent intent) 
                {

                    try
                    {
                        getShareSubject("Share Subject","Please describe why would you like to share this (optional):");
                    }

                    catch(Throwable e)
                    {
                        String err="Error11: " + e.getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), err, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }       

                    if(mShareSubj.equals(SUBJ_CANCEL)) return false;

                    int start = mTextView.getSelectionStart();
                    int end = mTextView.getSelectionEnd();          
                    int tvID=mTextView.getId();
                    String sPlaceType = (tvID==R.id.textTransl2) ? "t":"p";
                    mTextURL=mTextURL+"?t="+sPlaceType+"&s="+start+"&e="+end;

                    mANText=mTextView.getText().subSequence(start, end).toString();

                    if ("com.facebook.katana".equals(intent.getComponent().getPackageName()) ) 
                    {
                        //mfacebooksharer.shareStatus(subject, text);
                        // Toast.makeText(this, "Facebook sharing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        shareOnFacebook();
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(!MyApp.mC.hasFlag(Cookies.FL_Sharing, m_context))   
                            return true;
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,   getShareBody(intent));
                        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mShareSubj);

                        getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);

                        return true;
                    }


                }

            });
        }

        return true;
    }

    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

        return false;
    }

    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        //Log.d(TAG, String.format("onActionItemClicked item=%s/%d", item.toString(), item.getItemId()));

        int start = mTextView.getSelectionStart();
        int end = mTextView.getSelectionEnd();
        long note_id=-1;

        mANPlace=UserDataSQLHelper.NOTE_PLACE_TEXT;
        mANText=mTextView.getText().subSequence(start, end).toString();
        if(mbPurport) 
            mANPlace=UserDataSQLHelper.NOTE_PLACE_COMM;

        mANStartPos=start; 
        mANEndPos=end;
        mScrollPos = mScrollT.getScrollY();

        switch(item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.cab_menu_fav:

            if(!MyApp.mC.hasFlag(Cookies.FL_TextHighlight, m_context)) return false;

            note_id=MyApp.mUserDB.addNote(m_dbtype, m_dblang, mCurrBookID, mCurrSong, mCurrChapterNum, mCurrTextNum, mRowID, UserDataSQLHelper.NOTE_TYPE_HIGHL, mANPlace, start, end, mScrollPos,
                    mANText, "", "");

            break;
        case R.id.cab_menu_comment: 
            if(!MyApp.mC.hasFlag(Cookies.FL_TextHighlightAddCommentsQuestions, m_context)) return false;

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoteEditor.class);
            intent.putExtra("NOTEEDIT_ACTION", NoteEditor.ACTION_ADD);
            intent.putExtra("NOTEEDIT_TITLE", "Add Question or Note");

            startActivityForResult(intent, SUBACT_ADDEDITNOTE);
            break;

        }
        if (note_id!=-1){ 
            ReloadText();
            AddTags(note_id);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    }
}
```

Text selection menu xml code is here:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


       <item
        android:id="@+id/cab_menu_fb"
        android:orderInCategory="10"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/cab_facebook"
        android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        android:title="@string/cab_menu_fb"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/cab_menu_fav"
        android:orderInCategory="20"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/cab_highl"
        android:title="@string/cab_menu_fav"/>


      <item
        android:id="@+id/cab_menu_comment"
        android:orderInCategory="30"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/cab_comment"
        android:title="@string/cab_menu_comment"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a brand problem instead of Android version problem? Please provide Android version of the Note 2 and the Z2 for reference.

Comment: Samsung's Android version is 4.4.2 and Sony's version 4.4.4

Comment: Are you tried to use support library? I don't know exactly but it contains actionbar related things..

Comment: No I have not. Do you know any good tutorial on this?

Comment: Does touching any button close the CAB, or is that the case only with the last button (which opens the overflow)?

Comment: Have you tried using Android Studio's debugger? Step through the code and see how the calls differ.

Comment: If I press copy to clipboard button it copies the selected text and closes the action bar. So probably this problem is about my custom, additional buttons.

Comment: I tried to debug it a while ago and did not succeed. Maybe I should install all the sdk source files so that I could debug into android source code...

Comment: So it's only the `R.id.cab_menu_comment` case that triggers the premature close? Does commenting out either `putExtra` line change the behavior?

Comment: I'v had a lot of issues with ActionBar in the past as well. Working with the new Toolbar API helped a lot. You should look into it as a last resort perhaps. Good luck :) Here's a good tutorial for Toolbar: http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Comment: Your logcat doesn't seem to output everything there. I assume you filtered the output on the logcat panel. Generally, for example, if you have a problem with the keyboard, the log is written with the keyboard app tag and not with the app who called them. There's probably some sort of output there, but remove the filter first.